# Delete items from Laravel Session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel

im trying to delete items from the Laravel Session Array, but with no luck so far.

I store my values in a Session array using the Session::push() method:

```
  Session::push('event_date_display', Input::get('event_date'));
  Session::push('event_start_display', Input::get('event_start'));
  Session::push('event_entry_display', Input::get('event_entry'));
  Session::push('event_end_display', Input::get('event_end'));
```

I can access the values like normal arrays:

```
        @for($i=0;$i<Session::get('dates');$i++)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ Session::get('event_date_display')[$i] }}</td>
            <td>{{ Session::get('event_start_display')[$i] }}</td>
            <td>{{ Session::get('event_entry_display')[$i] == '' ? '-' : Session::get('event_entry_display')[$i] }}</td>
            <td>{{ Session::get('event_end_display')[$i] == '' ? '-' : Session::get('event_end_display')[$i] }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{URL::route('termin-loeschen', $i)}}" class="del"><span class="icon-spam"></span>Loeschen {{ $i }}</a></td>
          </tr>
        @endfor
```

But I can't figure out how to delete them. I tried Session::forget('event_date_display')[$index], but this deletes the whole array. Then I tried looping and unsetting, which isn't working either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you call `Session::forget('event_data_display')[$index]`, there is no point at which that `$index` variable gets passed into the `forget()` method. So Laravel won't see it, and will unset the entire 'event_data_display' index of the Session array.

To unset the value at that index, you'll probably need to do something like this:

```
$event_data_display = Session::get('event_date_display');
unset($event_data_display[$index]);
Session::set('event_data_display', $event_data_display);
```

Laravel's Session does support *adding* to arrays via a specified index like this:

```
Session::push('user.teams', 'developers');
```

So you might also be able to access that index of the array like so:

```
Session::forget('event_data_display.' . $i);
```

I haven't tried it but it's worth a shot.

When you call `Session::get('event_data_display')[$i]`, the reason that works is because PHP retrieves the array value from `Session::get('event_data_display')` *before* it looks for the value stored at the `$i` index.

When you call `Session::forget('event_data_display')`, the `forget()` method can only act on what is passed to it.

Comment: $event_data_display = Session::get('event_date_display');
unset($event_data_display[$index]);
Session::set('event_data_display', $event_data_display);

This works, thanks.

Comment: +1 for this answer `Session::forget('event_data_display.' . $i);`

Answer (score 4):

I solve it using the following code. Just pass the value that you want to delete in the array as an `"id"` to your controller like the code bellow

```
public function removeAddTocart(Request $request)
{
    $remove = ''.$request->id.'';

    if (Session::has('productCart'))
    {
        foreach (Session::get('productCart') as $key => $value) 
        {
            if ($value === $remove)
            {
                Session::pull('productCart.'.$key); // retrieving the value and remove it from the array
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!, i tweaked it a little bit with the session helper, it would be more clean

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
session()->save();
```

after clearing the session. Then only the values in session get deleted.

Answer (score -3):

It appears to me that you are trying to remove a value from an `array` stored in the `sessions`. To do this I would think that you want to do the standard array `unset($array[$key])`.

So it would be something like `unset(Session::$array[$key]);` I believe.

Answer (score -5):

Just use below code to remove all session in laravel

$request->session()->flush();

Comment: How is this ... remotely applicable?