# Laravel 5.1 - Removing item from array in session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session-variables

I have laravel application and I store items in a basket using the session.

**function that adds item to basket**

```
public function addItem($id)
    {
        session()->push('user.basket', $id);
        return back();
    }
```

**function which removes item from basket**

```
public function removeItem($id)
    {
        session()->pull('user.basket', $id);
        return back();
    }
```

When I add items this works fine, however when I come to remove an item that's in the basket the whole basket is removed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242401/delete-items-from-laravel-session-array

Comment: does your application support storing multiple elements with same id in the basket?

Answer (score 2):

The `session()->pull('key','default')` method removes the item with `key`, and returns the `default` value if it does not exist.

There is no way to delete item from array directly, you need to implement it:

```
$array = session()->pull('user.basket',[]);
unset($array[$id]);
session()->put('user.basket',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, an array has values and each value has a key (`['key1' => 'value1']`), the value could also be another array. In your example, you have used an array (`user.basket`), each dot represents a new level of the array.

**Remove by value**

You push your ID to the session array. You don't specify any key and it will therefore get an unknown key, so you want to remove it using a value (your ID). The variable `$valueToRemove` in the example is your ID.

```
session()->put('user.basket', array_diff(session()->get('user.basket'), [$valueToRemove]));
```

*To explain: Replace the `user basket` with everything in `user basket` that isn't in the array that only contains the `$valueToRemove`.*

**Remove by key**

Lets say you know the which key (position) you want to remove, for example if you loop throw the array `foreach(session()->get('user.basket') as $key => $value)`. Then you can remove the specific key using `forget`.

```
session()->forget('user.basket.'.$keyToRemove); // example: 'user.basket.7'
```

**Your code**

```
public function removeItem($id)
{
    session()->put('user.basket', array_diff(session()->get('user.basket'), [$id]))
    return back();
}
```