# How to remove an item from session array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Here is the problem I have a session

```
session('products')
```

this is actually an array that contains id

```
session('products')
array:4 [▼
0 => "1"
1 => "2"
2 => "4"
3 => "1"
]
```

Now I want to delete lets say `4` How do I do that? I tried method

```
session()->pull($product, 'products');
```

But it didn't work!

Other solution

```
session()->forget('products', $product);
```

it also didn't work

Comment: Do you only have the value or do you have also the key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete items from Laravel Session array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242401/delete-items-from-laravel-session-array)

Comment: @LucaJung Only the value

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You AFAIR have to firstly retrieve whole array, edit it and then set it again. If you want to delete by product ID, which is as I assume an array value, you can use this: [PHP array delete by value (not key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key#7225113)

```
$products = session()->pull('products', []); // Second argument is a default value
if(($key = array_search($idToDelete, $products)) !== false) {
    unset($products[$key]);
}
session()->put('products', $products);
```

---

#### Misunderstood question

`Session::pull` takes first parameter as the item do delete and second as the default value to return. You have mistaken the order of arguments. Try:

```
session()->pull('products'); // You can specify second argument if you need default value
```

As I can see in [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L601), `Session::forget` expects string or array, so you should specify only the first parameter:

```
session()->forget('products');
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for and thanks a billion for explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

**This method isn't tested:**

```
Session::forget('products.' . $i);
```

note the dot notation here, its worth the try. If that isnt working, you can always do this:

```
$products = Session::get('products'); // Get the array
unset($product[$index]); // Unset the index you want
Session::set('products', $products); // Set the array again
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way in case you have a function to delete an item from a cart

```
public function deleteProductoCart(Producto $producto) {
    $cart = \Session::get('products');
    unset($cart[$producto->id]);
    \Session::put('products', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('tu-ruta');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt on answering the question. Stack Overflow [requires content to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684). Please consider re-writing your answer in English.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this functionality as well but ended up doing it like this. Since it's **by value** you want to remove, this method is also **built for removing multiple products** in one hit!

For example; removing productIds 5, 11 and 541 from a cart with products)...

```
// Get the current session products
$products = session()->get('products');

// Remove certain products
$products = array_diff($products, [5, 11, 541]);

// Set the session with the new altered products
session()->put('products', $products);
```