# laravel removing item from session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4

I am using sessions to store cart items. I am able to modify session items but having trouble in removing them. This is the function I'm stuck on

```
public function removecartitems(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');

    $items = Session::get('cart.items', []);

    foreach ($items as &$item) {
        if ($item['id'] == $id) {
            unset($item);
        }
    }

    //Session::set('cart.items', $items);
    $request->session()->put('cart.items', $items);

    return 'removed';
}
```

This is How i add items in session

```
$Item = array("id"=>"$productid", "name"=>"$name", "qty"=>"$qty", "rate"=>"$rate", "preview"=>"$preview", "front"=>"$front", "back"=>"$back");



    $request->session()->push('cart.items', $Item);
```

Comment: Can you show how you add items to the cart?

Comment: yes let me update in question

Comment: It would be much easier to retrieve your items, remove the line item and then reassign the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, just an FYI, you don't need to wrap your variables in `" "`.

I would suggest changing your logic for adding items to the cart from using `push()` to `put()` and to also use the product id:

```
$item = [
    "id"      => $productid,
    "name"    => $name,
    "qty"     => $qty,
    "rate"    => $rate,
    "preview" => $preview,
    "front"   => $front,
    "back"    => $back,
];

$request->session()->put('cart.items.' . $item['id'], $item);
```

Then your remove method would look something like:

```
public function removecartitems(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->forget('cart.items.' . $request->input('id'));

    return 'removed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
if($request->session()->has('cart.items') && $request->session()->get('cart.items') != '') {

  $request->session()->forget('cart.items.name');

}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: but i want to remove a specific item not all items...and item is array which contains a unique id

Comment: @sunilkumar Please follow this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609844/how-to-remove-an-item-from-session-array-in-laravel)