# How to remove an item from laravel session by giving the index of the session array

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

Hello I'm new to Laravel I store family member details inside the session by using the below method and i want to delete family member by using the index of the session please someone help me.

`session()->push('families',$request);`

[image: this is how my array looks like]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an item from session array in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609844/how-to-remove-an-item-from-session-array-in-laravel)

Comment: those methods are not working for me i want to delete an item from the session by giving the index please help me if you know

Comment: check my answer

Comment: nop those two methods are not working i already tired

Comment: can I see your code implementation? and what error did you get?

Comment: this is what happens when i tried that second method https://pasteboard.co/HVYjcLB.png

Comment: change `Session::push('families', $families);` to `Session::put('families', $families);` please

Comment: if it works I will update my answer

Comment: Oops that worked thank you very much

Comment: Actually, using `pull` function will also work (which is the first method). But since I dont know your complete code I prefer to use the second method. By the way, you're welcome

Comment: yeah i'm using the second method now "push" was the reason behind this anyhow thank you once again

Comment: any time my brother @mohamedruzaik ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do it using PHP `array_search` function:

```
$families = session()->pull('families', []);
    if(($key = array_search($deleteID, $families)) !== false) {
        unset($families[$key]);
    }
session()->put('families', $families);
// PS: specify index you want to remove on $deleteID variable
```

or more simple way:

```
$index = 0; // let's say it's index 0
$families = Session::get('families'); // save the array
unset($families[$index]); // remove value from array based on index
Session::put('families', $families); // set the array again
// PS: specify index you want to remove on $index variable
```