# How do I remove array from session in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, e-commerce

I am developing a shopping cart in laravel in which I want to remove array in the session but it is not working.

I have tried these:

https://www.allphptricks.com/simple-shopping-cart-using-php-and-mysql/
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/remove-array-element-from-session?page=1

but it did not work

```
foreach($request->session()->get('shopping_cart') as $key => $value){
    if($value['code'] == $request->remove_id){
        $request->session()->forget("shopping_cart.". $request->remove_id);
        break;
    }
}
array:4 [▼
  "fh5hhr34" => array:5 [▼
  "name" => "Wilma Goodman"
  "code" => "fh5hhr34"
  "price" => "412"
  "quantity" => "2"
  "image" => "product_pics/1566372402.jpeg"
   ]
  "ghtzzr" => array:5 [▼
  "name" => "Lillian Hays"
  "code" => "ghtzzr"
  "price" => "187"
  "quantity" => "4"
  "image" => "product_pics/1566372214.jpg"
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: What is the array we're looking at? The output of the entire session or the output of only the shopping cart? Please show us the code you ran to produce that output.

Comment: *"How do I remove array from session in laravel"* Simply [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an item from session array in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609844/how-to-remove-an-item-from-session-array-in-laravel)

Comment: @waterloomatt it is the output of the entire session. the code that generated the json is print_r(Session::get('shopping_cart'));

Comment: I can't see why that wouldn't work. What debugging steps have you taken? Ex. have you verified `$request->remove_id` is what you expect? Does `shopping_cart.fh5hhr34` actually exist in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```php
foreach(session('shopping_cart') as $key => $value){
    if($value['code'] == $request->remove_id){
        session()->forget("shopping_cart.$key");
        break;
    }
}
```

If still does not work you can try to `save` the session at the end of the `foreach`, i.e.:

```php
foreach(session('shopping_cart') as $key => $value){
    //....
}
session()->save();
```

Please let me know if it works.